# Is it possible to custom kernel compilation with rtai 5.2 patch on lubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, kernel, compiling

I am trying to compile Linux kernel 4.14.89 with rtai patch 4.14.89 but after compilation my custom kernel unable to boot.

Comment: Can you provide more information ? like the errors messages or the things you have tried to solve your problem

Comment: I am getting blank black screen while booting my new kernel.

Comment: when I change quiet splash in grub during boot to text then boot window stuck at crng init done..

Comment: We would require a lot more information to be able to help.

Comment: Yes. First I refer rtai installation document to install rtai patch. After successful compilation I update grub file. Then I reboot my system in new kernel with rtai patch. Now while booting it shows message is random: crng init done and stuck there only.

Answer (score 0):

If you compiling your kernel but not showing booting grub screen first you must be check your install Virtual box in distributor of linux setting must be check ISO file is right way to attach

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1298209)